# elementFromPoint() full document alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to recover a value from a cookie, which is somewhere on the Y-axis where the user clicked. I then want to find the parent `<h2>` from that click (if it helps, all the `<h2>`s are the first child of a `<div class="_bdnable_">`). Here is what I have so far:

```
var bookmarkLocation;
function getBookmarkPos() {
    if ($.cookie("bookmark-position") !== null) { 
        $(".bdnable").each(function(i) {
            var scrollTopTop = $(this).offset.top;
            var scrollTopBottom = $(this).offset.top + $(this).height();
            // var screenWidth = parseInt(screen.width/2);
            // alert(screenWidth);
            // var bookmarkPosition = parseInt($.cookie("bookmark-position"));
            // alert(bookmarkPosition);
            // var query = document.elementFromPoint(screenWidth, 50).nodeName;
            // alert(query);
            if ($.cookie("bookmark-position")>=scrollTopTop && $.cookie("bookmark-position")<=scrollTopBottom) {
                bookmarkLocation = $(this).closest("div").children(":nth-child(1)").text();
            }
        });


        if (bookmarkLocation == null) {
            bookmarkLocation = "Unknown";
        }
    } else {
        bookmarkLocation = "No bookmark set";
    }

    $("#bookmarklocationspan").html(bookmarkLocation);
}
```

In the commented out section is where I tried to use *getElementFromPoint* and then realized that it only checks the visible area. Not good, because the scrollable Y-axis on the page is 1000s of pixels tall.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the y-coordinate of the click from the cookie, why not simply compare all H2's y-position and pick the one which is the next "higher" one? Your approach looks like it's compares whether the user has clicked directly on the H2 instead of the article/button below it?

Just an idea - don't rate it's style, think its prettey messy:

```
var $myH2 = $('h2');
var clickY = <COOKIE_VALUE>;
var currentY = 0;
var foundH2ID = '';
for (var i = 0; i < $myH2.length; i++) {
 var h2Y = $($myH2[i]).position().top;
 if (h2Y <= clickY && h2Y > currentY) {
  currentY = h2Y;
  foundH2ID = $myH2[i].id;
 }
}
```

Or maybe I got you wrong?

Comment: You're welcome! And of course you are free to modify the code as you like :-)